# ES6 - How to import and alias a named export's member?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Say I have a package that exports a `User` type:

```
export const User: {
  name: string;
};
```

And I want to use the `name` property aliased as `username` in my code. In normal JavaScript I'm able to do something like this:

```
const { User: { name: username } } = require('user.js');

/* do something with `username` ... */
```

I want to convert the file I'm working with into TypeScript and so I'll use ES6 module imports. How can I achieve the same as above using `import` instead of `require`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) objects in static [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statements, but you can rename them using the `as` keyword:

```ts
import { User as USER } from "./user.js";
```

If you are okay with using a [dynamic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) import, you can destructure:

```ts
const { User: { name: username } } = await import("./user.js");
```

There are pros and cons to both static and dynamic importing methods which you can read about in the links I shared.